# VBA Code to delete Temp files made by word

Tags: excel, vba, temp

I have code to delete all files in a folder:

```
ChDir "C:\test\" 'path
Kill "C:\test*.*" 'type
```

However, when I open a doc file and save it as a text, it creates a temporary file named ~$*****.doc and these files do not get deleted.

How would I do this?

```
Sub BatchConvertCSV()

'declarations
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim NewName As String
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ApplicationFileSearch As New FileSearch
Dim iCnt As Integer

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'search for all.doc files in specified folder
With ApplicationFileSearch
.NewSearch
.LookIn = "C:\test\"
.SearchSubFolders = False
.FileName = "*.doc"
.Execute
j = .FoundFiles.Count
i = 1
MsgBox ("Found files " & j)
'open each document
Do While i < j
Set objWord = Documents.Open(FileName:=.FoundFiles(i))
With ActiveDocument
iCnt = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count
'Somewhere here we need to decide on the placement for an if statement to filter out the doc files for 35 and 39 fields.
'If the doc file does not have that amount of fields
'MsgBox ("Found fields " & iCnt)
If iCnt > 30 And iCnt < 40 Then
.SaveFormsData = True
'save open file as just form data csv file and call it the the vaule of i.txt (i.e 1.txt, 2.txt,...i.txt) and close open file
NewName = i
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\test\Raw Data\"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=NewName
objWord.Close False
Else
End If
End With
i = i + 1
Loop
'repeat to the ith .doc file
End With

ChDir "C:\test\" 'path
Kill "C:\test\*.*" 'type
```

Comment: aren't those temp files hidden by default?  If they are, you'd have to add a flag for that.  Something like: del C:\test /A:H

Comment: Or unset the hidden attribute, similar to http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/DeleteFiles.htm

Comment: Close the doc file after saving it as a text file.

Comment: the doc file closes, automatically I believe. however, it still leaves a temp file

Comment: Post the complete code.

Comment: Posted the code above.

Comment: you're never disposing of the Word object, which is probably why the temp files aren't being removed as part of the normal Word shutdown process.  Try releasing the Word object and seeing if that helps.

Comment: @sous2817 you should post that as the solution.

Comment: I can see this working. Going to give it a shot.

Comment: Nope, hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").getfolder("C:\Test")
    For Each file In .Files
        If Left(file.Name, 2) = "~$" Then
            Kill "C:\Test\" & file.Name
        End If
    Next file
End With
```

You can, of course, refine that filter as you see fit.

The only problem I can see with that is that you're removing `files` from `.Files` while you're looping through them; it might work, but it's probably safer to add each file to a list instead of killing it in the ForEach loop, and then go through and kill everything in the list afterwards.

EDIT:
A little more research. According to [this article](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/DeleteFiles.htm), you can't use `Kill` on read-only files. This means you need to use the `SetAttr` command to remove the "read-only" flag. Here's some code that might help:

```
Dim strDir, strFile As String
strDir = "C:\Test\" 'Don't forget the trailing backslash
strFile = Dir(strDir & "~$*", vbHidden)
Do Until strFile = ""
    If Len(Dir$(strDir & strFile)) > 0 Then
        SetAttr strDir & strFile, vbNormal
        Kill strDir & strFile
    End If
    strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

As you can see, that includes a check that the file actually exists before trying to delete it; as we're pulling that file up with `Dir` the check shouldn't be necessary, but your experience suggests that extra precautions are needed here. Let me know how that works.

Comment: @Crownife Hmm. Have you made sure that the directory specified in the `kill` line ends with a backslash, as in my example? Also, are you running the `kill` in the `For Each` loop or from an array as suggested in the answer? I don't have Office on my machine at the moment but will be able to check on Monday.

Comment: I'm running your code separately from mine to test it out. The backslash is included as well and the error 53 pops up. This shouldn't be related to ending the word process because its still the same after I restart the computer. Error 53 is file not found which is odd because when I run a scan of the folder using a vba code, it does see the hidden files.

Comment: Not sure why that should be (I've tested it myself and it works), but I've updated the answer with another approach that might work.

Comment: I did it another way. Deleting the folder gets rid of those files, so it worked out that way.